# Equivalent definition of the measurable sets of a finite outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Usually if I have a outer measure $\mu^*:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$  induced by a measure $\mu:\mathcal R \to \mathbb R$ where $\mathcal R$ denotes a ring over $\mathbb R^n$ we define the $\mu^*$-measurable sets as those sets $A$ for which $Q \subset \mathbb R^n \Rightarrow \mu^*(Q)= \mu^*(Q\cap A)+ \mu^*(Q\cap A^c)$. But I just read that if $\mu^*$ is finite, a set A is measurable if and only if $\mu^*(\mathbb R^n)=\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(A^c)$. How could I show this? (Any hints would also be welcome)

Answer (score -1):

Because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of $\sigma$-finite measure.

This definitions works on any space $X$ on which there is an outer measure $\mu^*$ induced from a $\sigma$-finte premeasure.

For any $E\subset X$
if $\mu^*(X) = \mu^*(E) + \mu^*(E^c)$

then $E$ is $\mu^*$ measurable